# How do I specify the proper ID of the JSON data than I load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to get the right `i` values for each and every one of my `response` values (JSON loads). How do I do that?

Lets say I have 10 JSON files. All of them must be loaded, stored and displayed to the client in the proper order.

So it should look something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    $.getJSON(files[i], function (response) {
        console.log(i);
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

The result of the `response` is what we would expect - the contents of the file, but the variable `i` always seems to be the same (= files.length). My explanation for this would be that JS is not a language that waits for a specific action to complete, it can do a lot of actions in the same time (forgot the scientific name for this).

Comment: you mean it's "asynchronous". basically your code is firing off `files.length` worth of nearly simultaneous requests at the server, not waiting for the previous one(s) to finish. when the `function(response)` does kick in, `i`i is almost guaranteed to be some **OTHER** value than the current response was sent out with.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that your callback isn't *closing over* the value of `i` in effect when it's registered; every callback sees the same instance of `i`, which ends up having the value it has after the loop completes (which is `files.length`).

The sensible thing to do, with jQuery, is to use `$.each` as coder says. But the way to solve it with pure javascript would be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    (function(idx) {
        $.getJSON(files[idx], function (response) {
            console.log(idx);
            console.log(response);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

By making, and then immediately calling, the anonymous function, you rebind the value in `i` to a new local variable named `idx` scoped to that function. Each callback then carries around its own `idx`, so it will end up logging the correct value (what `i` was when you registered the callback, instead of what it became later). This is actually exactly what's happening when you use `$.each`, since `each` has you pass in an anonymous function that receives the index as a parameter.